# Forward different subdomain requests to different localhost ports in NET Core

Tags: .net-core

I want to forward different subdomain requests to different localhost ports in NET Core.

How Can I achieve this?

Seems like net core middleware or reverse proxy like yarp is not supporting this.

Comment: Not that many details in your "question", but isn't that what yarp was made for? Can't you simple just create one route per host?

Comment: This isn't a matter of forwarding. Ports are at the IP level, far lower than HTTP. There's no domain in a TCP packet. The domain is included in the HOST header of an HTTP request. The server receives the request and looks up which handler/endpoint to call to handle the request. First, you need to configure DNS to map the subdomain requests to your machine's IP. Then, you need to configure your ASP.NET Core application to listen to *all* ports you way want, although just a single one is enough. Finally, you can configure different endpoints for different host headers

Comment: YARP and all reverse proxies can to what you want to - forward to specific IPs and ports based on the HOST header of the HTTP request